# "Subquery" in Power BI

Tags: subquery, relationship, powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMVTN.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueyVG.png)

As you can see, there is a link between ID from Table 1 and IdPays from Table 2 (the link is obviously the letter A,B,...). My question is, is it possible to make a link between the two tables without having to duplicates any column ? Is it possible to create a link immediately on the letter of the ID column ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything can be done, but from perspective of data structuring (and performance) it is really a bad idea.

```
= Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Table2", (Earlier) => Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [IdPays] = Text.Start(Earlier[ID],1)), Value.Type(Table2))
```